# noMethodError on a < symbol ruby

Tags: ruby, bubble-sort, nomethoderror

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMAqV.png)

The link for the error is above; I keep getting a noMethodError for a symbol and I am very confused

```
numList = [4,3,78,2,0,2]

def bubbleSort(list)
  again = true

  while again
    copy = list
    i = 0
    until i == list.length do
      list.each_with_index do |num, index|
        if list[index+1] < num 
          tempNum = list[index+1]
          list[index+1] = num
          list[index] = tempNum
        end
      end
      i = i+1
    end

    if copy != list
      again = true
    else
      again = false
    end
    p copy
  end
end

bubbleSort(numList)
```

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&google your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: You are trying to index into list with an index that doesn't exist. `list[index+1]` at the last index in the list will return `nil`.

Comment: thx, I added (if index < list.length-1) and now it works!!

Comment: Your question has been answered but in future when you reference an exception (here `NoMethodError`) please include the complete error message and line of code where it was raised. That often pinpoints the error. Here you are trying to execute `list[index+1] < num ` which is `nil < num`, but `nil` does not have a method `<`. As `nil` is an instance of `NilClass` this is equivalent to saying `NilClass` does not have an instance method `<`.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Tip: Instead of the `if`, just do `again = copy != list` which directly assigns the result. Even better: `loop do ... break if copy == list` Having the `!=` in there leads to double negation: Break loop if copy is not *not* equal to list.

Comment: Tip: If you want to compare pairs: `list.each_cons(2) do |a, b|`, or with indexes: `list.each_with_index.each_cons(2) do |(a,ai),(b,bi)|`

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you are iterating with an index:

> ```
> list.each_with_index do |num, index|
> ```

But this includes the *last* index, which you're trying to access one past.

> ```
> if list[index+1] < num
> ```

`list[index+1]` return `nil`, which will give the error you're seeing.

```
irb(main):083:0> nil < 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):83
        1: from (irb):83:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass)
```

It'd be important to avoid this access. I would also suggest avoiding the `again` boolean flag. Rather use `loop` and `break` out of the loop at the appropriate time.

```
def bubbleSort(list)
  loop do
    copy = list
    i = 0
    until i == list.length  
      list.each_with_index do |num, index|
        next if index == list.length - 1
      
        if list[index+1] < num 
          tempNum = list[index+1]
          list[index+1] = num
          list[index] = tempNum
        end
      end
      i = i+1
    end

    break if copy == list
    
    p copy
  end
end
```

---

Taking a step back and looking at how bubble sort works though, your implementation can be improved.

Each cycle through the array a bubble sort will advance the largest element to the end of the array. You don't need to cycle over the whole array each times, but can decrease the inner loop by one iteration each time.

You can also track the number of swaps. If no swaps are performed, the array is clearly sorted already, and the outer loop can be exited.

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 1 |  (starting state for loop)
+---+---+---+---+

  >---<
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 1 | (swap 4 and 2)
+---+---+---+---+

      >---<
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 1 | (swap 4 and 3)
+---+---+---+---+

          >---<
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 | (swap 4 and 1)
+---+---+---+---+
```

Three swaps are performed. The last position in the array is sorted.

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 4 | (starting state for loop)
+---+---+---+---+

      >---<
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | (swap 3 and 1)
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | (no swap needed for 1 and 3)
+---+---+---+---+
```

One swap is performed. Now the last two positions are sorted.

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 4 | (starting state for loop)
+---+---+---+---+

  >---<
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | (swap 2 and 1)
+---+---+---+---+
```

One swap is performed. We know the last three positions are sorted. The first position therefore is sorted.

If the array is *already* sorted and we keep track of swaps:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | (starting state for loop)
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | (no swap needed for 1 and 2)
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | (no swap needed for 2 and 3)
+---+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | (no swap needed for 3 and 4)
+---+---+---+---+
```

Since zero swaps are performed, the array is known to be sorted. While bubble sort is worst case O(n^2), this technique can make it best case O(n).

```
def bubble_sort(arr)
  (arr.length-1).times do |x|
    swaps = 0

    0.upto(arr.length-x-2) do |i|
      if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
        temp = arr[i+1]
        arr[i+1] = arr[i]
        arr[i] = temp
        swaps += 1
      end
    end

    break if swaps == 0
  end
  
  arr
end
```